# Roots of $x^n-a$ in a cyclic extension $E$ of $F$ where $E$ has dim. $n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I have tried searching for this question but I have not seen anything similar. If there is please let me know. The whole question is the following:

Suppose $F$ is a field that contains $n$ distinct $n ^{th}$ roots of $1$ and $E/F$ is a $n$-dimensional cyclic extension of $F$, then $E=F(u)$ where $u^n \in F$. Show that an element $v\in E$ is a root of the polynomial $x^n-a$ if and only if $v$ has the form $bu^k$ where $b\in F$ and $1\leq k \leq n$.

Ideally I would like a good starting hint for the forwards direction. By forwards direction I mean if $v\in E$ is a root of the polynomial $x^n-a$,then $v$ has the form $bu^k$ where $b\in F$ and $1\leq k \leq n$. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out eventually. Like I mentioned in a comment I believe the intended meaning was to assume $E=F(u)$, $u^n \in F$, even though in the question it reads as something we need to prove. As I was told I only need to prove the if and only if statement.

We have $Gal(E/F)=\langle \sigma | \sigma^n =1\rangle$ by the assumptions. Furthermore, from the assumption $E=F(u)$, $u^n \in F$, I was able to see from guidoar's proof that $\sigma(u)=\xi^{-1} u$ where $\xi$ is a primitive root of unity in $F$.

Now suppose $v$ satisfies $x^n = a$ for $a\in F$. Then $v^n=\sigma(v^n)=\sigma(v)^n$. This implies

$$(\sigma(v)^{-1}v)^n=\sigma(v)^{-n}v^{n}=1.$$

Which shows that $\sigma(v)^{-1}v$ is a root of unity in $F$. Let $\xi^k$ be the root of unity in $F$ such that $\sigma(v)^{-1}v = \xi^k\tag*{$\ast$}$  for $k\leq n$. Then

$\begin{align}\sigma(vu^{-k}) = \sigma(v)\sigma(u^{-k})&=v\xi^{-k}\sigma(u^{-k}) \tag*{Using $\ast$}\\
&=v\xi^{-k}\sigma(u)^{-k}\\
&=v\xi^{-k}(\xi^{-1}u)^{-k}\\
&=vu^{-k}.\\
\end{align}$

As $\sigma$ is the generating automorphism this holds for all automorphisms in $Gal(E/F)$, hence $vu^{-k} \in F$. Let $b \in F$ such that $vu^{-k} =b$. Then $v=bu^k$ with $b\in F$ and $1\leq k \leq n$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** by hypothesis $\mathbf{Gal}(E/F) = \langle \sigma \mid \sigma^n = 1\rangle$. Consider $\xi \in F$ a primitive root of unity (why does it exist?). Then $N_{E/F}(\xi) = \xi^{[E:F]} = \xi^n = 1$. Now apply Hilbert's Theorem 90 and see where that leads you.

**Edit**

Following your comment: if $\nu := t^{-1}$ then $\sigma(\nu) = \xi \nu$ and thus $\sigma(\nu)^i = \xi^i \nu$. These are $n$ distinct roots of $m(\nu, F)$, so by degree considerations $m(\nu, F) = \prod_i (x- \nu \xi^i) = x^n - \nu^n$.

In particular we get $\nu^n \in F$, and since $[F(\nu):F] = \deg m(\nu,F) = n$, we have $E = F(\nu)$.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I still don't seem to understand. Using Hilbert's Theorem 90 as you pointed out, there exist some $t\in E$ such that $\xi = t(\sigma(t))^{-1}$. Since $F$ contains the roots of unity, then the roots of $x^n-a$ in $E$ would be $v\xi,v\xi^2,...v\xi^n$. Then combing the two facts we have $v t(\sigma(t))^{-1},v (t(\sigma(t))^{-1})^2,...v( t(\sigma(t))^{-1})^n$. Then from here I do not quite see how this helps.

Comment: @miloman101 edited!

Comment: So I think I was a little unclear in the question, but also the question as it was given to me may be poorly worded. I believe the $E=F(u)$ for $u^n \in F$ is a given assumption not something we need to prove. By forwards direction I meant if $v\in E$ is a root of the polynomial $x^n-a$, then $v$ has the form $bu^k$ for $b\in F$ and $1\leq k\leq n$. I am sorry for any confusion that might have caused! I really appreciate the help!

Comment: What's $a$? Is is $a = u^n$?

Comment: I am not sure honestly, I typed the problem exactly as given to me. It does not mention which field $a$ is in or if $a=u^n$. But my assumption is that $a\in F$ and $a$ is arbitrary. At least that is how I interpreted the question about which field $a$ is in.